# condicion de dias a mostrar boostrap datepicker

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, bootstrap, datepicker

Tengo el siguiente problema:
Tengo una lista de servicios y cada servicio tiene un tiempo de produccion, por ej:

Servicio 1 --> 7 Dias Habiles.
Servicio 2 --> 5 Dias Habiles.

Dicho listado proviene de Mysql a traves de un SELECT anidado por ajax.
Lo que necesito, es que dependiendo del servicio y su cantidad de dias de tiempo de produccion, estos (dias) sean agregados al datepicker como dias que no se pueden seleccionar. Por ej, si hoy es 03 de Abril del 2018 y el servicio seleccionado tiene 7 dias habiles, no se pueda seleccionar una fecha menor a estos 7 dias y no se deben contar los dias sabado ni domingos.
Actualmente, ya tengo bloqueados los dias sabados y domingos en mi datepicker (no es gran cosa, pero es informacion que se debe saber).
Archivo que devuelve la consulta por ajax del select:

```
$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hijos WHERE id_cliente = ".$id1."");
echo "<select name='tratamiento' class='form-control select2' >";
echo "<option value='0' selected='selected' disabled='disabled'>Elija Tratamiento</option>";
    while($registro = mysql_fetch_row($consulta))
        {
        echo "<option value='".$registro[0]."'>".$registro[1]." --> Tiempo Estimado Entrega: ".$registro[5]." a ".$registro[6]." Días Hábiles</option>";
    }
echo "</select>";
```

?>

Select HTML:

```
<div class="form-group m-b-15">
 <label class="control-label">Seleccione Tratamiento</label>
  <select name="subcategory" class="form-control select2" id="subcategory" >
   <option value='' selected='selected'>Seleccione Tratamiento</option>
  </select>
<span class="help-block" id="error"></span>                                                 
</div>
```

Contenido del Date Picker:

```
.datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  autoclose: 'true',
  language: 'es',
  daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
  startDate : currDate
})
```

Si alguien tiene alguna nocion de como poder realizar esto, se los agradeceria muchisimo. 
Saludos y gracias a todos a todos por su informacion.

Answer (score 0):

Con la opción **beforeShowDate** de datepicker.

Esta opción te da a elegir en si el día representado es seleccionable o no, una clase css adicional y un popup tooltip para mostrar algo ese día.

Esta opción pasa por cada día del clendario desde starDate hasta alrededor de 2 meses más

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
    var selectable = true;
    // Comprobar que el date que me da datepicker
    // es igual a la fecha que yo quiero hacer no seleccionable
    if(date === myDate){
        selectable = false;
    }
    return [selectable, "", ""];
  }
});
```

Ten cuidado con la comparación de fechas porque seguramente tu la tengas en un formato y **beforeShowDay** esté en otro formato de fecha.

Comment: Perfecto. hare las pruebas necesarias y te comentare como me va. Actualmente, uso el formato dd-mm-yyyy solo para representacion, al guardar, lo hago en formato yyyy-mm-dd. Gracias por la info. Saludos